# Magento 2 API: Filter orders by extension attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, orders, search-criteria

I have an extension with an attribute assigned to `order items` called `warehouse`.
I can see this attribute under the property "`extension_attributes`".
I need to filter orders based on this attribute.  I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Example API response snippet:

```
[items] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [extension_attributes] => Array(
            [warehouse] => MyWarehouse
        )
    )
)
```

The following filter generates an internal error:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=warehouse,searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=mywarehouse,searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Any suggestions on how I can filter orders using the warehouse attribute via the `API`?

### - Additional point on  this question:

In this case, if we will follow [Fooman blog](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html).Then can we  filter the collection by  the **extension*** attribute?

> - Collection filter by this extension Attribute Should be run Fast?
> - If we use custom db table for save this extension attribute table    then how can filter?
>     Should  it work magento frontend and backend also.
> - where in need do modification and which class need to add  or any reference blog ?

Wait for good  and describe/brief answer on this points?

Comment: No one answered?

Comment: Have you declared your attribute at `Module>/etc/extension_attributes.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, man, I did not it .

Comment: You did or did not? Maybe this is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your query string contains commas (`,`) when it should contain ampersands (`&`):

```
/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=warehouse&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=MyWarehouse&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Secondly, as other answers have mentioned in more detail, the query will only work if the attribute on which you're filtering is present as a column in the database table(s) being filtered.

Comment: this is  not given my answer:(

Comment: Please explain in brief

Comment: @AmitBera you have to save the attribute in corresponding table of db and call API accordingly, check my answer.

Comment: @AmitBera you are asking me to explain about the extension attributes or about using the extension attributes in search criteria in API

Comment: I am asking about search criteria  in API

Comment: @Neo, I already check it.But donot get answer filter is not working on search

Comment: @AmitBera, are you able to figure out how we could use extension attribute in search criteria for order API?

Answer (score 2):

The searchCriteria does not filter results from API response instead from the db/collection instead, if custom attributes  in extension_attribute are not available in the db as a column in the table from where the data is being fetched it will not come in response.

For eg. I make following API call -

```
 http://example.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=random&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=random&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Then as there is no column called random in sales_order table (from which the API is fetching response ) , I get following error ;

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'random' in
>   'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order` AS
>   `main_table` WHERE ((`random` = 'random'))

So, if you have to call your custom data in the API you have to save in respective table in a new column, then you  can call it normally using column name as the fiter field and value as your desired value, as below ;

```
 http://example.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=column_name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=desired_value&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

I have tested it myself, I hope same works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing this (Magento 2.2), I don't think there's a way to filter on extension attributes. Although they're present in the underlying collection's `select` if you define a `<join>` in `extension_attributes.xml`, it seems like you can't filter on it.

It's up to the extension developer to provide a way to filter on values of an extension attribute. You can see an example in the Amazon payments module:
https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/blob/master/Plugin/CustomerCollection.php#L59

In that plugin, you can see how they expect the table to be already joined (as it's defined in `extension_attributes.xml`), but apply the filter manually.

Answer (score 0):

@AmitBera I am not 100% sure for this and it doesn't give your all question answer but I think first you need to first use JoinProcessor to search criteria and then use filer. you can check more how to do it on this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

I came across a requirement where i need to add new table with few fields and they need to work as an extensible attribute for sales order. Whenever new sale order is created a record is added in the table with fields like order id and integration status. I implemented the extension attribute successfully and this attribute was available in REST API and we could update them through API as well. However, i could not use the new field from my table in the API search. This will give column not found issue from sales order table. I struggled a lot to use my extension attribute field in API search.

My data in table was as below:
[image]

Similarly, data in API response was as below for an example order:

```
"integrations_sales_order": {
                "order_id": 2776573,
                "integration_status": "Created",
                "integration_status_updated_at": null,
                "integration_fail_message": null
            }
```

However, when i try to use integration status in the API request as a search criteria then it did not work. my search criteria was as below

```
{{url}}/rest/all/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=integration_status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=Created&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

But i could make it work by changing the search criteria as below then it works:

```
{{url}}/rest/all/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=extension_attribute_integrations_sales_order.integration_status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=Created&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Please note that `extension_attribute_integrations_sales_order` is the attribute code you have used from `extension_attributes.xml` file.

Filter in my API call will show up in response as below:

```
{
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "extension_attribute_integrations_sales_order.integration_status",
                    "value": "Created",
                    "condition_type": "eq"
                }
            ]
        }
```

This is how I could use my extension attribute in the search criteria for API call for Sales order. Hope this will help some one. Good luck.